# Is there another way to filter on several lists?

Tags: 2007, list

SharePoint 2007 lists

So I have several lists and need to be able to filter them by text but I am unable to use the Text Filter web part because admins have it locked down (something about performance issues).  I am a site curator limited to using LVWP and CEWP and CANNOT use SharePoint Designer nor InfoPath.  I know I can link one list to another but I have 4 lists to try and filter and in some cases the data I need to filter is in a multi line text field.

All of these lists were created before I got involved with maintaining them so just wondering if there is a way to filter on the data.

Wasn't sure if there was some code that can be put in CEWP on a web part page that might help.  Keep in mind I am newb at SharePoint and not that great of a coder.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how limited you are, you can specify the filter in the query string of the address. Use a CEWP to link to it, or a normal link list.

For example, http:// sharepoint/lists/contacts/allitems.aspx?&FilterField1=FirstName&FilterValue1=Cindy, will filter items where the first name is Cindy. The best thing to do is go to your list, filter it just through the UI and then copy the address bar.

This should work on a web part page, however if a web part doesn't have the field, it'll error out.

HTH